# Control row spacing with kable / kableExtra booktabs (RMarkdown)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

By default, `kable()` with `booktabs=T` in R Markdown (kableExtra) leaves more space after every 5th row of a table. Is it possible to change / omit this spacing for a single table within a document? I like this feature for my larger tables in the document but when a table only has 7 or so rows, it looks funky.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Hao. I didn't know to search for \addlinespace. The other post indeed answered my question. Apologies for the duplication.

Comment: Haha, no worries. In fact, since the other question was asked in a very LaTeX-rich way, I do hope your question can help other people who are not so familiar with LaTeX find the answer.